# Referenced entity is output each time instead of once

Tags: 7, entities, views

I use out-of-the-box *articles* content type to which a I added en *entity reference field* so I can assign multiple users to that article. I used this reference in order to be able to display multiple authors for that article.

The end goal is, that when the detailpage of an article is displayed, to have a block listing the assigned users and per user listing the nodetitles that reference this users (so-called authors). Basically, trying to mimic the out-of-the-box author-functionality using entityreference. In views' preview function, I would then add a nid that uses the conextual fileter.

The output that I want then would look as follows:

**From John Doe:**
Lorem Ipsum
Ipsum Lorem
Irem Lopsum

**From Plain Jane:**
Irem Lopsum
Ipsum Lorem

I *almost* managed to configure this with views

1. Added a contextual filter that pulls in the `nid` so I can filter the assigned users based on that `nid`.
2. Configured a relationship for the users that are referenced by the `nid` that is displayed. I use this in my first field to display the assigned users. This works fine
3. Configured a second relationship for the nodes referencing my users. Also pulled in this relationship when making my second field that is `content:title`.

What I get instead though and what I don't want is the following:

**From John Doe:**
Lorem Ipsum
**From John Doe:**
Ipsum Lorem
**From John Doe:**
Irem Lopsum

**From Plain Jane:**
Irem Lopsum
**From Plain Jane:**
Ipsum Lorem

I read this [drupal answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42352/display-number-of-times-content-is-referenced-in-content), where someone wants to display an *amount* of referenced entities. This seems close to my issue, but I have the feeling that my problem isn't really one with aggregation or grouping. Still not sure of course, but I just can't seem to understand how it would fit my case. Semantically though, the word *grouping* obviously suggests I'm on the right track. Technically OTOH, it's not quite making sense to me, since it seems to group data rather than markup the way I want it to.

I also watched both the NodeOne video's [1](http://vimeo.com/33251051) and [2](http://vimeo.com/33252553) mentioned in drupal answer stated above. Other than fiddling with aggregation settings, I also deleted the default sort criteria as suggested. Didn't help.

Comment: Immers, apologies for the problem there. We currently have a troll doing the rounds, if you see anything else like that please just flag it for our attention. Thanks

Comment: *heads up that is