# Count of child nodes of a specific content type

Tags: views

I have a content type Grants, with multiple other "child" content types that have a node reference GrantID back to the Grant content type. For example, Sub-Grants and Publications are two of the other content types, both with a node reference GrantID.

I'd like to have a view of Grants, displaying a table of each grant that has columns with the total number of Sub-Grants, Publications, etc. For example, grant 511 has 21 sub-grants and 15 publications.

Using aggregation and a relationship with GrantID (field_grantid) - reverse I can get a count of ALL the times that GrantID has been used by any other content type (36 in the example above). How do I just get the count of Sub-grants vs. Publications?

Comment: Is [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42352/display-number-of-times-content-is-referenced-in-content) what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank,s for this - I had seen this other post (and the nice video) when searching but I'm not sure that it fits my scenario. The relationships in the video are different - the "parent" evaluation content type has the node reference to either "children" (training or presentation). In my case I have the node reference on the two children.  Let me know if you think I'm wrong though, I appreciate the reply!